# How to write a flowtype for arrow function with generic type

Tags: flowtype

How do I write flowtype for the following code?

The function argument is an array of generic type.

```
const fn = (array) => Promise.resolve(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
const fn = <T>(array: Array<T>): Promise<T> => Promise.resolve(array[0]);
```

Relevant documentation: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

Comment: Sadly a [separate type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46596235/4228942) won't work :(

Comment: how would be a async arrow function?

Comment: @norbertpy there's now an answer on the linked question showing how to do this with a separate type.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, it now has my own answer which obviously is not a garbage. It's a _tremendous_ answer.

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini async arrow function is just a syntactical sugar for returning Promise, so you can write something like `() => ?Promise<void>`