# flow generic type for function expression (arrow functions)

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype, arrow-functions, parameterized-types

I usually try to keep flow function types separate from their implementation. It's a slightly more readable when I write:

```
type Fn = string => string;
const aFn: Fn = name => `hello, ${ name }`;
```

rather than:

```
const aFn = (name: string): string => `hello, ${ name }`;
```

When using generic types we can write:

```
const j= <T>(i: T): T => i;

const jString: string = j('apple'); // √
const jNumber: number = j(7);       // √
```

But how can I separate this type from a function expression?

```
type H<T> = (input: T) => T;
const h:H<*> = i => i;              // --> WHAT SHOULD GO FOR '*'?

const hString: string = h('apple'); // X error
const hNumber: number = h(7);       // X error
```

What should be used for `*`? `any` would work but that's not what I want.

In haskell this is a non-issue:

```
identity :: a -> a
identity a = a

identity "a-string" // √
identity 666        // √
```

See [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAEgPAFQHxQLxQBQEsB2YCuwAXFAgJRooIDcAUAMYD2OAzsFABZHwBUK6WSlCx0GzNpwDKwAE64A5iTZyc8tJwwByAIZgwAGwiayY1uw4A5fAFsARhBkkcN+zPUcMAdjKjaAM3wcemAsZigAK0QkbDxCEnJ4qABvWigoGQhgfBkcYVjgOgBfWlMJcOkVRShlBXVwrV0DIx9S9nCrOwcnFwc6rx8gA)

Comment: If I do `<T>(i : T) => i` with `flow dump-types` I get `<T>(input : T) => mixed`, which is kind of weird to be honest.

Comment: That should be `<T>(i: T) => T` which is dumped to `<T>[type: (i: T) => T]`;

Comment: Do you mean that the type of `<T>(i : T) => i` should be `<T>(i: T) => T`? If so I agree. Unless you meant that I got the definition wrong, it's not really a type definition, that's the actual function definition with the types.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I have noticed that if I use [bounded generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-generic-types-act-as-bounds), it'll work:

```
type H<T> = <T: *>(input: T) => T;
const h:H<*> = i => i;

const a: string = h('apple');      // √
const b: number = h(7);            // √
const c: {} = h({ nane: 'jon' });  // √
```

Don't ask me WHY.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Flow, or is it not? Would be interested in the WHY!

Answer (score 2):

```
 type H<T> = (input: T) => T;
    const h2:H<*> = i => i;   
    const h3:H<*> = i => i;   
    const hString: string = h3('apple');
    const hNumber: number = h2(7);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

I think the underlying issue with your code and type definitions is based on a misunderstanding of a particular property of generics (aka parametric polymorphism): **Parametricity**.

Parametricity states that a generic function must not know anything about the types of its polymorphic arguments/return value. It is type agnostic.

As a result, a generic function must treat each value associated with a polymorphic type equally, regardless of the concrete type. This is pretty limiting, of course. When a function doesn't know anything about its argument, it can't do anything with it other than returning it unchanged.

Let's have a look at an incorrect generic function:

```
const f = <a>(x :a) :a => x + "bar"; // type error
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAQwHwAoAeMBcaAlAWkhjHgNQwBEARmgE60DcMA9BzFAJ4AOAUxiCmTEEyA)

`f` doesn't type check as expected because `f` must not treat `x` as a `String`. Flow enforces parametricity.

Please note that generics are much more useful in connection with higher order functions. Here is an example of a correct generic higher order function:

```
type F<X, Y> = (x: X) => Y;

const apply = <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X) :Y => f(x);

const sqr = (x :number) :number => x * x;
const toUC = (s :string) :string => s.toUpperCase();

apply(sqr, 5); // does type check
apply(toUC, "foo"); // does type check
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYgPADQDRQJoD4oF4oAoAeAXFAgJTaaoDcAUDQMYD2AdgM7BQCGYYANiNiiIUGXADNi8ZGnQoiJcoVQUoYgqVoMW7KKwCOAJ0EEohZgFcAtgCMIBxRZt2V+KACoo+WkzYdgjAFUAYWNWU3YDAEtmAHNFCOiYlVYAOn8AnjsgzlYIXA06bj4QXH0DFABWAqL+XHSglAAiMUZGRo0gA)

Why would you define a specific version of `apply` for every possible type? Just apply it to values of arbitrary type provided that the types of `f` and `x` are compatible.

### Conclusion

When you have an unbounded generic function, you can apply it to whatever value you want - it always works as expected. **So there isn't really a reason to declare a distinct function for each possible type.** Smart people have invented polymorphism in order to avoid exactly this.

A problem remains, though. As soon as you separate the generic type definition form the function declaration, Flow no longer enforces parametricity:

```
const f = <a>(x :a) :a => x + "bar"; // type error

type G<a> = a => a;
const g :G<*> = x => x + ""; // type checks!?!
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAQwHwAoAeMBcaAlAWkhjHgNQwBEARmgE60DcMA9BzFAJ4AOAUxiCmTEEwBQMGTEl8hMAOLoKyMogppWk0JFgBzAioBUayuQs1abTtwXDgAC0HAA1hACEAfk+SgA)

So your question is still reasonable and unfortunately, I can't offer you a recipe. Hopefully, Flow's behaviour will change in future versions.

In your own answer, you suggest using bounded generics. I wouldn't do that because it solves a problem that doesn't exist at all and because it seems to be a misuse of this sort of polymorphism.

Comment: Yeah, my answer seems like a hack until flow comes up with a solution but it actually works as expected and type checks the wrong usages. But thanks for your detailed answer.